# Disable stacklabel for scatter line in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a combination chart (stack column and scatter line). And I use stacklabels to display the total output of the stack column but it show the value of scatter line. Anyone idea can disable the scatter line value?

Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/kcsophic/h2c0Lrow/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'center',
      style: {
        color:'#FFF'
      },
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    plotLines: [{
      color: '#0520ed',
      width: 4,
      value:    12,
      zIndex: 4,
      label: {
        text: 'Target = ',
        style: {
          color:'#FFF'
        },
        align: 'right',
        rotation: 90,
        x: 5,
        y: 25
      }
    }]
},
legend: {
    reversed: true
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
},{
    name: 'Target Line',
  type: 'scatter',
  showInLegend: false,
  marker: {
    enabled: false
  },
  data: [19],
  enableMouseTracking: false
}]
```

});

[image: REMOVE THE VALUE!]

Answer (score 1):

You should simply disable stacking for the scatter series:

```
series: [..., {
  ...,
  stacking: false,
  type: 'scatter'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/473vs1ny/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.stacking

Comment: Omg!!  Just like this? Why so easy?! I used 4 hours++ on this issue!! I focus google on 'DataLabel' or 'YAxis' or 'plotline'.... Thank you